# Autohotkey - I need to click down and hold for a specific amount of time

Tags: autohotkey

I found an autohotkey script that I need to tweak so that pressing the button results in the left mouse button being held down for approximately 1800 miliseconds. This is what I've got so far but I'm doing something incorrectly.

```
F1::
alt := not alt
if(alt)
{
Click down ; Sleep, 1800
}
Click up
return
```

Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Read in the manual about Comments in Scripts (https://autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#Comments) and in the Tutorial how to put several commands in code (https://autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm#s13)

Answer (score 1):

Semicolon punctuation mark, `;`, is used for comments.

The Sleep command is commented out, so remove the semicolon:

```
Click, down
Sleep, 1800
```